# Accordion change class in clicked element, easy way to do it?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-accordion

**HTML**

```
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accord-header">
    <a class="fleft">1 Title</a>
    <a class="fright exp"></a>
  </div>
    <div class="accord-content">
     ble ble ble
    </div>
  <div class="accord-header">
    <a class="fleft">2 Title</a>
    <a class="fright exp"></a>
  </div>
    <div class="accord-content">
     bla bla bla
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".accordion .accord-header").click(function() {
      if($(this).next("div").is(":visible")){
      $(this).next("div").slideUp("slow");
      } else {
        $(".accordion .accord-content").slideUp("slow");
        $(this).next("div").slideToggle("slow");
      }
    });
});
```

Basically, what it does, it an is accordion for my articles list. Now I need to change class of `<a>` element "fright exp" to "fright imp" when 1 tab is clicked, same thing for next tabs. "fright exp" is symbol + and "fright imp" is -, is there a easy way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".accordion .accord-header").click(function() {

      if($(this).next("div").is(":visible")){
        $(this).next("div").slideUp("slow");
        //clas that you want to add
        $(this).find('a').eq(1).addClass('yourclass');
        //clas that you want to remove..if any
        $(this).find('a').eq(1).removeClass('yourclass');
      } else {
        $(".accordion .accord-content").slideUp("slow");
        $(this).next("div").slideToggle("slow");
      }
    });
});
```